# ByteBuffer.allocateDirect().asFloatBuffer() vs BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer()

Tags: java, lwjgl

I just solved a bug and I'm not sure why. Creating a 4x4 projection matrix in LWJGL, for use in a vertex shader..

This line causes problems. It fails silently and my `mat4` in the shader is stuck as all zeros (as if it was never written).

```
FloatBuffer mProj = ByteBuffer.allocate(4*16).asFloatBuffer();
```

This works as expected.

```
FloatBuffer mProj = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
```

As a sanity-check, I confirmed that my floats are 4 bytes. So what's the difference?

Comment: What is `BufferUtils`? A lwjgl class?

Comment: Good question. The class is `org.lwjgl.BufferUtils`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only [difference](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.lwjgl.lwjgl/lwjgl/2.8.0/org/lwjgl/BufferUtils.java#BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer%28int%29) between those two is *possibly* the byte order. You can set it as

```
FloatBuffer mProj = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * 16).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
```

Comment: That's exactly it, thank you! I had looked at the documentation for ByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer, but it made no mention of byte order there.